# Specific Connection Between Representation of Algebras and Functors

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory

Some background: I'm not very adept with category but I am trying to organize some of the content from my Representation Theory and Algebras class with concepts from category theory.

We have been specifically focusing on representations of associative algebras over a field. We have already seen the equivalence of representations $\Theta:A\rightarrow End_K(V)$ of a $K$-algebra $A$ and an $A$-module $V$.

We have also seen that two representations are equivalent if $\Theta_1=\psi^{-1}\Theta_2\psi$, for a vector space isomorphism $\psi$.

How can one organize this with the language of category theory? The last piece of information leads me to think that representations, like $\Theta$, are analogous to functors and $\psi$ is serving as a natural transformation. What am I to think of the equivalence of representations of $A$ and $A$ modules?

Comment: We can regard $A$ as an additive ($K$& linear) category with one object, then representations indeed become functors to the category of $K$-vector spaces and morphisms of representations become natural transformations.

Comment: @Berci That's an answer.